# Select all records from table A and join table B to get A's property

Tags: mysql

I can not figure out how I should do it...

Table 'child':

```
idchild | name | idability
--------------------------
   1    | Joe  |    1
   1    | Joe  |    2
   2    | Peter|    1
   2    | Peter|    3
   3    | Kate |    4
```

Table 'ability':

```
idability | ability
-------------------
     1    |   run
     2    |   read
     3    |   write
     4    |   swim
```

For example, Joe can 'run' and 'read' but can't 'write' or 'swim'.
And I need a list like this about Joe's ability:

```
ability |  
-----------------
  run   |   +
  read  |   +
  write |   - 
  swim  |   -
```

I've tried several SQL queries in different ways (using 'NOT EXIST') but never got the correct result. I hope somebody can tell me how I should do this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be ok:

```
select ability.ability, if(child.idability,'+','-') from ability left join child on ability.idability =child.idability and child.name="joe";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select `child`.`idChild`,`child`.`name`, `child`.`idability`, `ability`.`idAbility`,`ability`.`ability` from `child` inner join `ability` on `child`.`idAbility` = `ability`.`idability` order by `child`.`name`, `ability`.`ability`
```

You can remove columns that you don't need.

Comment: This lists only those abilities which child has, not every ability. I need to list every ability and mark which child has.